# Spotify Token Issue

Tags: javascript, spotify

**The goal of the app:** To solve the current problem of Alexa not being able to find playlists that the user has created, and instead substituting some random playlists from its ecosystem with a partial title match (even though, technically using the 'my' prefix during the invocation was supposed to solve that problem [it does not]).

My first step in this adventure was to build a Javascript app using Spotify's Web API to create a faux voice interface, that essentially does the same thing: uses voice input to find and start playing a playlist that the user asks for, specifically, in this case, one that they have created.

My second step is to put into this test app the logic of limiting the scope of the Spotify search to only the pool of playlists the user has created.

**Current state:** I have built the basic backbone, and the result got me as far as matching the playlist that I requested that I was also the creator of.

**The issue:** The building of the uri/play request keeps failing with the error specifically being that the token was not supplied.

**The attempt: I currently have a 2-step flow:**

1. Use a token-generating function to create the token (based on the
   supplied ID, Secrete and Scope settings.
2. Manually plug-in the token and run the app.

**Token Generator:**

```
const client_id = 'xxxx';
const client_secret = 'yyyy';
const redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:xxxx';

const authEndpoint = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize';
const scopes = ['playlist-modify-private','playlist-read-private','playlist-modify-public'];
const state = 'some-state-of-my-choice';

// Set up the authorization URL
let url = `${authEndpoint}?response_type=token&client_id=${client_id}&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(redirect_uri)}&scope=${encodeURIComponent(scopes.join(' '))}&state=${encodeURIComponent(state)}`;

// Redirect to the authorization URL
window.location = url;
```

**Actual App**

```
const accessToken = 'xxxx'; 
const userId = 'yyyy;
let playlistName; 

function playPlaylist(playlistId) {
  fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play?context_uri=spotify:playlist:${playlistId}`, {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  })
  .then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Failed to start playback.');
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error:', error.message);
  });
}

// Create a new instance of the SpeechRecognition API
const recognition = new window.webkitSpeechRecognition();

// Set the language to the user's default language
recognition.lang = navigator.language;

// Start the recognition process when the user speaks
recognition.onresult = (event) => {
  playlistName = event.results[0][0].transcript.toLowerCase(); // Assign value to playlistName

  // Fetch playlists
  fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/playlists?limit=50`, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log('Fetched playlists:', data.items); // Log fetched playlists

    const playlistNames = data.items.map(item => item.name.toLowerCase());
    console.log('Playlist names:', playlistNames); // Log playlist names

    const playlists = [];
    for (const name of playlistNames) {
      if (name.includes(playlistName)) {
        playlists.push(data.items[playlistNames.indexOf(name)]);
      }
    }

    console.log('Matching playlists:', playlists); // Log matching playlists

    if (playlists.length > 0) {
      const playlistId = playlists[0].id;
      playPlaylist(playlistId);
    } else {
      console.log(`No playlist found with the name "${playlistName}"`);
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error fetching playlists:', error.message);
  });
};
```

**Assumptions:**

1. I'm supplying an improper scope for the type of token this app needs
   to operate on playlists.
2. I'm not building the uri/play request correctly.

Would love your help here guys.

Comment: That’s a lot of words that seem tangential, but: you’re saying things work except for playback? Isn’t there a different scope for that (like “streaming” or something)?